# Isolated Storage Setting (saving & retrieving from different views)

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-7, isolatedstorage

I have two views (MainPage.xaml  & Settings.xaml)

I want to save a string in my Settings view
& retrieve its content in the MainPage

Here's my code, but i'm getting an error:

**Settings.xaml.cs :**

```
var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
                settings.Add("setPlan", "This is my text that i want to retreive");
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
var location = settings["setPlan"].ToString();
```

THE ERROR IS :The name 'settings' does not exist in the current context.

But isn't this "setPlan" string supposed to be in my sandBox and accessible from any view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need:

```
var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings; 
var location = settings["setPlan"].ToString();
```

in `MainPage.xaml.cs` ?

`settings` looks like it's scoped to the method it's being called from, in Settings.xaml.cs.